# Why are the Angularjs Material Cards being pushed below the content on a view change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a page that when visited after a view change, the content is being added to the bottom of the page instead of the view being repopulated with the new content. This is only occurring on this on page with the AngularJS Material Design Directives specifically the cards. All other directives work without hesitation. If the directives are removed from this page then the view will change state without the content being added to the bottom of the page as it should.

I also get the following error on my directory page: error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! 
Is there another way I need to write this service to prevent this from happening? Is this the reason for my directory page being pushed to the bottom of another page?

An example of what this looks like can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiohab2dm4gzhcx/angular-issue.png?dl=0

=== DIRECTORY CONTROLLER ===

```
angular.module('main').controller('directory', ['$scope', 'rows',    function($scope, rows){
$scope.imagePath = 'http://lorempixel.com/250/250/business/'; 
$scope.people = [
    {
        name: 'asdfasdf',
        dept: 'asdf',
        desc: 'asdfasdf',
        phone: '33333333',
        email: 'adsfasdf@asdf.com',
        photo: 'something.jpg'
    }
$scope.chunked = function(){
    return rows($scope.people, 3); 
}
```

=== ROWS SERVICE ===

```
angular.module('main').factory('rows', function()
{
    return function(objects, num)
    {
        var newArr = [];
       for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i+=num) {
        newArr.push(objects.slice(i, i+num));
       }
       return newArr;
    }
});
```

=== HTML ===

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="directory" id="directory">
  <h1>Directory</h1>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="people in chunked()">
  <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="person in people">
  <md-card md-theme="{{ showDarkTheme ? 'dark-purple' : 'default' }}" md-theme-watch="">
  <md-card-title>
  <md-card-title-text>
    <span class="md-headline">{{person.name}}</span>
    <span class="md-subhead">{{person.dept}}</span>
    <span class="md-subhead">{{person.desc}}</span>
    </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary" aria-label="Favorite" href="mailto: {{person.phone}}">
            <md-icon class="material-icons">phone</md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary" aria-label="Settings" href="mailto: {{person.email}}">
            <md-icon class="material-icons">email</md-icon>
        </md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

=== ROUTES ===

```
angular.module('main').config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.
    when('/:paramB',
    {
        templateUrl: function(params)
        {
            params.paramB = params.paramB.replace(':', '');
            return "/pages/" + params.paramB;

        }
    }).when('/', {
            templateUrl: function(){
                return '/home.asp'
            }
    })
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed an issue with ng-repeat. If there is a iterator warning then this can effect the view state. The solution for this was to prevent this error by utilizing the following. This is the long way, outside of creating a factory/service, however this satisfies Angular.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
  <div class="col-sm-4">{{people[$index].name}}</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">{{people[$index + 1].name}}</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">{{people[$index + 2].name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning an object from your factory, rather than a function, like so:

```
angular.module('main').factory('rows', function()
{
    return {
        calculate: function(objects, num)
        {
            var newArr = [];
           for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i+=num) {
                newArr.push(objects.slice(i, i+num));
           }
           return newArr;
        }
    };
});
```

Then use it like this: `return rows.calculate($scope.people, 3);`

Comment: I am still getting the error about having too many iterations.

Comment: My best guess is that it has to do with `ng-repeat="people in chunked()"``. If you could set up your example in pluncker I could test some things. Also check your syntax in the controller, it seems to be missing some closing brackets

Comment: The Plunker is not working the way I have this set up in my actual coding environment.

Comment: Here is an image of what this looks like in actuality The page should not have the content above only the directory information. Refreshing the page fixes the issue but clicking on the link ruins it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiohab2dm4gzhcx/angular-issue.png?dl=0

Comment: The way you setup your routes is a bit off. Essentially what you currently do is setup the same route twice. You either need to setup a second route, e.g. when('/something/:paramB'), or add the param to the second route - delete the first one - and handle the different cases within your controller using $routeParams

Comment: Not sure what you mean by having this set up twice. If the page is at / it  will display /home.asp. This page is different then the page that already has `<ng-view></ng-view'>. Also if any other page is called such as /#/:test.asp it will go into /pages/test.asp and display this inside of the default.html with only contains the ng-view. I don't think the issue is the routes but instead Angulars Material Directive for cards.